# Variable variables in SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

I have 'simple' problem :-)

I'm reading large XML file using this:

```
$node = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());
```

$node have elements severity, class...
I can compare them like this:

```
if($node->severity==WARNING){
```

Or show them like this:

```
echo $node->severity;
```

What I want to prepare if statements in advance reading posts variables like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Severity']) && !EMPTY($_POST['Severity'])){
  $Severity[]=$_POST['Severity'];
  foreach($Severity as $Severityval){
   foreach($Severityval as $Severityvalues){
    $searchquery .= '($node->Severity==' .$Severityvalues. ') || ';
   }
  }
}
```

Then I want to use $searchquery inside XML reader:

```
if($searchquery){
 echo $node->severity;
}
```

But, this always return true and everything is shown :-(

My variable is properly created, if I echo it shows
($node->Severity==WARNING)

Maybe screen shot can explain my problem:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please tell us what's going wrong ?

Comment: Just edited, If($searchquery) always return true

Comment: try to add a condition in your foreach to set only that variable if $node->severity==WARNING and add strlen(trim($searchquery)) > 0 or isset($searchquery) on your if statement !

Comment: Both gives me true. As I said, I can echo $searchquery and it shows proper criteria. I think problem is with $node-> ...something like that

Comment: I think it is rather a design problem. You must have to test in your foreach statement and after test it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['Severity']) && !EMPTY($_POST['Severity'])) {

  $Severity[] = $_POST['Severity'];

  $i = 0; 

  foreach($Severity as $Severityval) 
  {
    foreach($Severityval as $Severityvalues) 
    {
      if ($node->Severity == $Severityvalues) {
        $i++;
      }
    }
  }

  if ($i > 0) {
    echo $node->severity;
  }
}
```

EDIT : I understand fully the problematic, if you had loaded one per one XML, you can do that (for each selected on node value - example work for severity, it's a good sample) :

```
$root_node = $your_var;

if(isset($_POST['Severity']) && strlen(trim($_POST['Severity'])) > 0) {

  $severities_selected = array_values($_POST['Severity']);
  $severity = (string) $root_node->severity;

  if (in_array($severity, $severities_selected)) {
    echo "This XML contains one selected severity (".$severity.")";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I understand what you trying. Already tried something like that. But problem is that I have other POST variables to :-(. So my IF looks like this: if(($node->Severity==FATAL) || ($node->Severity==SEVERE) || ($node->Severity==WARNING)) && (($node->Class==Backup/Restore) || ($node->Class==Communication)){....

Comment: What is the final goal of this script ? To get a list of severities nodes ?

Comment: To filter xml file by different elements (severity, class, datetime...)

Comment: Mathieu thank you for your time. I just added screen shot of my form. Maybe there is some other way to establish this.. but have no idea

Comment: As I can see, you want to build SQL query form your template to your database ? Why XML objects ?

Comment: Hi. It is not SQL, I have exported data i zipped XML files. I don't want to import them in MySQL, just want to be able to show and search them.

Comment: I understand better, you want to parse the XML that contain the fields of research of the template ? How many XML have you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127883/discussion-between-mitja-and-mathieu-dormeval).

Comment: Have you had time to test ?

Comment: Perfect! This is so obvious solution, but I was blind :-) Thank you very much Mathieu

Comment: Happy to have helped you !